# How to take only a certain amount of power from one source when two power sources are connected in parallel

Tags: power-supply

I want to output 12V 45 watts to turn on a 12V 45 watt LED (motorcycle headlight). The image given is schematic of my target project. I need to draw only 15 watts from the battery and the rest of the energy will come from the "Rectified AC Source". If I just connected them in parallel the battery could be charging itself even draw all power from the battery. But by some magical way I need to draw only 15 watts from battery and rest from the AC source.

The AC source is just motorcycle's headlight socket's power. Which produces 30 watts at most. (Since the existing bulb is 30 watt halogen.)

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Some helpful search terms for you: "Load sharing" and "load balancing".

Comment: LED bulb ratings don't always say what power they actually consume, and just because a socket used to have a 30W device in it doesn't mean that it can't supply 45 watts just fine, and AC is different from DC.  So please _edit your question_ so that we know if the LED bulb is rated for AC, if it _actually consumes_ 45W or if it is a "45W equivalent" to a 45W halogen, the current rating of your bike's alternator, and the current rating of the fuse, if any, in the headlamp circuit.

Comment: If you have a 30W halogen bulb in there now and you replace it with a decently-efficient LED bulb that _actually consumes_ 45 watts, then you may find that you're now producing way too much light.

Comment: @TimWescott 
The purchased LED doesn't work on AC (actually the packaging doesn't mention anything about putting in AC source).  45 Watt is printed on the packet of LED light.  All I know is, there is a 30 Watt Halogen headlight (stock) in the socket. And the socket is AC. Since the manufacture put 30 watt bulb in there so I thought it produces maximum 30 watt energy. Somewhere I read that total 140Watt energy can be produced with my bike's alternator. But that gets distributed to run other electrical system obviously. I don't have any other information...

Comment: Does the bike's alternator not already charge the 12V battery?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yeah it charges the battery. But according to many users if they directly comnects such LED with battery leads the battery drainn too quickly and after a few days requires fully charging using a charger. That is why I have come up with this idea. But can't find a solution though.

Comment: Motorcycle power systems vary. Some power the headlight through a separate AC winding on the alternator, and the headlight goes out when the engine stops. Since you mention AC on the headlight socket I am guessing this is what you have, right? Exactly which LED bulb do you have, and what is the motorcycle brand/model?

Comment: @BruceAbbott You have guessed it correctly. LED: [Novosight N56](https://shorturl.at/fJVZ6), Motorcyle: [Honda Livo 110 CC](https://shorturl.at/afRUV), 
I have already bought this LED. So I am left with finding the perfect solution or destroying my battery gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Since the alternator is an AC source, we get pulsed current behind the rectifier. The battery can fill the gaps between the pulses. My first attempt would be a simple parallel ciruit with an additional diode to avoid a charge current flowing from the alternator back to the battery.
This may work perfectly and is worth an experiment.
V1 is the alternator, the simulation is not very realistic, because its inductance is ignored here. If I add an inductor in series with V1, the simulator dies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyaB2J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the above is not sufficient, a true current limiter for the battery side is possible. This is not very efficient, the MOSFET M1 must dissipate 12 W worst case. The circuit limits the battery current to 1.2A during the gaps. During the peak current pulses from the alternator, the battery current drops to zero. So the average load on the battery is a bit lower than 15W. A lower value for R4 can allow more battery current, this can be adjusted in a real world circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHC4IB.png)</sup>

D2 is used as a cheap voltage reference and the voltage divider R4/R5 sets the target current for the battery.

A more efficient solution would involve a current limited SMPS stage, I will draw one, when I have some more time.